# Not getting webhook request after enabling account linking when using DialogFlow v2 Google Actions

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, webhooks, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

We were trying to upgrade my DialogFlow Google Action from v1 to v2 of DialogFlow. After enabling DialogFlow V2 we are not getting request delivered to our webhook from Google Action if we are using account linking. When account linking is disabled, we are able to get the requests properly. But after enabling account linking the request does not get forwarded to your webhook.

We are not using Actions-for-google SDK and are using JSON requests and responses directly. V1 of the API works properly and is having no issues.

Please help resolve the situation.

Comment: @Prisoner Can you please help here, i was looking at your posts and you seems to have extensive experience in this. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Without seeing a list of your Dialogflow intents and your complete fulfillment, it will be difficult for another developer to reproduce this issue. Consider updating your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that duplicates the problem.